# Event listener not firing off in options.js in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

In my options page, in my chrome extension, I want to read the user input when the user enters their value and clicks the submit button.

**options.html**

```
<html>
<head>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<h1 style="font-family:Raleway;font-weight:200;text-align:center;font-size:50px;color:white;">Themes</h1>

<input type="number" id="day" value="2" class="day">
<button id = "button1">Submit</button>

  <script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**options.js**

```
...
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var day = document.getElementById("day").value; // get the current value of the input field.
    alert(day);
});
```

Comment: Don't invalidate existing answers with editing. If you still have the problem, make a new question or comment on the answer.

Comment: Alright, sorry. I changed it because of the answer below. I won't do so now. Again, sorry!

Comment: Did you reload the extension after making the change? Because Chrome caches all JS.

Comment: @Xan Yes I did, I'm only changing `addEventListener("click", function(){ ` in the code.

Comment: Just to be clear, I mean reload the whole extension - not just the options page.

Comment: I got it working, thanks. My other javascript code above it was interfering.

Comment: Ahh, the dreaded `...` code. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are listening for `change` not `click`.

`addEventListener("click", function(){})`

You're currently only running your function when the buttons value changes (and since a button has no value, this will never fire)

Comment: I've updated my options.js, it's still not alerting though. Thanks!